# Number of anagrams without consecutive identical letters.

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the letters $a,b,c,d,e,e,e,e,e$. I want to count the total number of ways to write words out of these $9$ letters such that no consecutive $e$ is allowed in the word. My attempt is that the number is $$n=\dfrac{9!}{5!}-\dfrac{8!}{3!}+\dfrac{7!}{2!}+6!+5!$$
where here $\dfrac{9!}{5!}$ represents the total number of anagrams from which we substract $\dfrac{8!}{3!}$ which represents the number of anagrams containing at least two consecutive $e$. Now we have to distinguish between the $e$ in which position so they are deleted twice so we have to add them back by adding $\dfrac{7!}{2!}$ if we have $3$ consecutive $e$ and $6!$ if we have $4$ consecutive $e$ and $5!$ if we have $5$ consecutive $e$. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Is that sum even positive?

Comment: More simply:  just put the $e's$ down, separated by blanks.  There are $4$ gaps between them, so each of those must be filled.  Happily you have $4$ letters with which to fill them, so...

Comment: is it $n=4!$? we have $4$ letters to fill in the $4$ gaps.

Comment: Yep, that's all it is.

Comment: With regard to your approach, what matters are pairs of consecutive $e$s.  You can have up to four such pairs (which overlap in $eeeee$).  If you have two pairs, they can overlap ($eee$) or be disjoint ($ee, ee$).  For instance, $aeebeceed$ has two disjoint pairs of consecutive $e$s.  An Inclusion-Exclusion Principle argument using pairs of consecutive $e$s can be made to work, but lulu's approach is much simpler.